# Replace dynamically loaded price with an image link if price contains 0.00

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bigcommerce

I want to make an image with a pop up link appear if the price is $0.00.

I am currently using a Jquery script that hides the dynamically generated price if it appears as 0.00. It works great! But it only shows text.

This is that script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ProductPriceRating em:contains("0.00")').text("Call For A Quote!");
$('.ProductPrice:contains("0.00")').text("Call For A Quote!");
$('.ProductDetails em:contains("0.00")').text("Call For A Quote!");

var text = $('.ProductPrice').text();
var comparingText = 'Call For A Quote!'
if(text == comparingText){
$('.productAddToCartRight').css('display','none'); 
}; 
</script>​
```

This is the pop up script I want implemented:

```
<a href="/request-quote/" onclick="return popitup('/request-quote/')"> 
<img src="/product_images/uploaded_images/requestquoteproductbutton.jpg" alt="Request A Quote" title="Request A Quote" /></a>
```

I am trying to get the image with pop up to show up instead of the "Call For A Quote".

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

EDIT: HTML

```
<div class='unknown'>
  <div class="Label">
    LNG_RRP:
  </div> 
  <div class="Value"> 
    GLOBAL_RetailPrice
  </div> 
</div> 
<div class="DetailRow PriceRow" style="GLOBAL_HidePrice"> 
  <div class="Label">
    GLOBAL_PriceLabel:
  </div> 
  <div class="Value"> 
    <em class="ProductPrice VariationProductPrice">
      GLOBAL_ProductPrice
    </em>
    GLOBAL_IncludingExcludingTax GLOBAL_YouSave 
   </div>
</div>
```

1/27/2014 Update
I am trying the following script now and I am able to get the button to show in place of the  0.00 dynamically generated text. I still need help getting the popup to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( '.ProductPriceRating:contains("0.00")' ).replaceWith( '<a href="/request-quote/" onclick="return popup(' + '/request-quote/'+ ')"><img src="http://www.hazardouslocationlighting.net/product_images/uploaded_images/requestquoteproductbutton.jpg" alt="Request A Quote" title="Request A Quote" alt="Request A Quote" title="Request A Quote") /></a>' );
$( '.ProductPrice:contains("0.00")' ).replaceWith( '<a href="/request-quote/" onclick="return popup(' + '/request-quote/'+ ')"><img src="http://www.hazardouslocationlighting.net/product_images/uploaded_images/requestquoteproductbutton.jpg" alt="Request A Quote" title="Request A Quote" alt="Request A Quote" title="Request A Quote") /></a>' );
$( '.ProductDetails:contains("0.00")' ).replaceWith( '<a href="/request-quote/" onclick="return popup(' + '/request-quote/'+ ')"><img src="http://www.hazardouslocationlighting.net/product_images/uploaded_images/requestquoteproductbutton.jpg" alt="Request A Quote" title="Request A Quote" alt="Request A Quote" title="Request A Quote") /></a>' );
</script>
```

Comment: so.. put some `.click()` handlers on the elements you're doing the replacing on, and have the click handler do your popup...

Comment: What .text('badger') does is replace each elements' text with 'badger'.
Please provide some more details: Could you post your html markup? It's hard to give any advice on markup specific code without the markup ;)

Comment: <div class="Label">%%LNG_RRP%%:</div>
                    <div class="Value">
                        %%GLOBAL_RetailPrice%%
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="DetailRow PriceRow" style="%%GLOBAL_HidePrice%%">
                    <div class="Label">%%GLOBAL_PriceLabel%%:</div>
                    <div class="Value">
                        <em class="ProductPrice VariationProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%</em>
                        %%GLOBAL_IncludingExcludingTax%% %%GLOBAL_YouSave%%
                    </div>

Answer (score 0):

instead of ...text("call for a quote") use ...html(anchorwithimage); Variable should contain the HTML code for the image and link as string.

Comment: I don't know how to place both the image and the string inside the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Alright with the markup provided you might want to go with something like:

```
var $elements = $('.ProductPrice.VariationProductPrice')

for(i = 0; $elements.length > i; i++){
  if($elements[i].text().indexOf('0.00') >= 0){
    $('.productAddToCartRight').css('display','none'); 
    $elements[i].html('<a href="/request-quote/" onclick="return popitup(' + '/request-quote/'+ ')"><img src="/product_images/uploaded_images/requestquoteproductbutton.jpg" alt="Request A Quote" title="Request A Quote") /></a>')
  } // endif
} // endfor
```

Still a lot of guessing involved... More details appreciated

Comment: for "put whatever you want to be here" will this work? "<a href="/request-quote/" onclick="return popitup('/request-quote/')"> <img 

src="/product_images/uploaded_images/requestquoteproductbutton.jpg" alt="Request A Quote" title="Request A Quote" /> </a>"

Comment: @PatrickWood Edited sample code. Feel free to try, though I am not sure what popitup(...) will do :)

Comment: Didn't do anything. Thanks for showing me how to write it in the sample.

Comment: Try this edit... If it still doesn't work try to provide more details. What does Firebug say?

Comment: http://www.ballasts.com/fluorescent/t5-ballast-fulham-auto-dim-1-bulb-elec-ph-35w-230v/

Comment: Going to pick this up again on Monday. Going home for the weekend.

Comment: Left a 1/27/2014 Update. Still can't get popup to work correctly.